# How to create a matrix with random numbers using typedef struct?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that creates a matrix with ones and zeroes which are randomly distributed, but I'm getting an error: expected identifier before numeric constant.

Can someone can give me some pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS 7
#define COLUMNS 7

typedef struct {
const int rows;
const int columns;
int board[ROWS][COLUMNS];
} game;

void newGame(game *session);

int main(void){

game session = {ROWS, COLUMNS};

 srand(time(NULL));

return 0;
}

/* Function:    newGame
 * Description: Set up a new game with random states for each brick.
 * Input:       A pointer to the game structure.
 * Output:      The game structure pointed to is updated.
 */
void newGame(game *session){

for(int r = 0; r<ROWS; r++){
    for(int c = 0; c<COLUMNS; c++){
        session[r].ROWS = rand()%2;
        session[c].COLUMNS = rand()%2;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please indicate which line gets the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
session[r].ROWS = rand()%2;
```

doesn't make any sense, `session` is a pointer to a single `game`, not an array, and `ROWS` is a `#define` that will be replaced by an integer here.

You probably meant:

```
session->board[r][c] = rand() % 2;
```

Also you are handling the size rather confusingly, it's both constant and run-time readable. I'm not sure that makes total sense to me, but perhaps it's handy for some reason.

Comment: I'm not sure of that, and it is false in C++.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch True, I didn't think that statement through (I don't care about C++ in a C question, but it wasn't true for C either). I removed it, thanks.